# day of week date format string java inside spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, date-format

```
val df = Seq("2019-07-30", "2019-08-01").toDF
val dd = df.withColumn("value", to_date('value))
dd.show(false)
```

according to the docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

`F` is the format string if I need to see the day of the week in month. And

```
dd.withColumn("dow", date_format('value, "EEEE")).withColumn("dow_number", date_format('value, "F")).show(false)

+----------+--------+----------+
|value     |dow     |dow_number|
+----------+--------+----------+
|2019-07-30|Tuesday |5         |
|2019-08-01|Thursday|1         |
+----------+--------+----------+
```

gives only the day of the week in the month, not the day of the week.

Which format string gives me the day of the week as a number /integer?

Obviously, I could use: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Data_Type_How_to/Date/Get_day_of_week_int_value_and_String_value.htm
But do not want to go for a UDF / want to use the catalyst optimized `date_format`. So which date format string gives me the desired result?

Comment: You mean monday to 1 and sunday to 7? "u"
`u Day number of week (1 = Monday, ..., 7 = Sunday) Number 1`

Comment: great. I somehow did not notice it in the docs. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentionned in the comments, you are looking for the `"u"` format.

Also, from spark 2.3.0 you might want to use `dayofweek` method, which is faster [dayofweek documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

> your code is correct instead of **"F"** just use **"u"** like below

```
dd.withColumn("dow", date_format('value, "EEEE")).withColumn("dow_number", date_format('value, "F")).show(false)
```

[image]